# Post Submissions and 404 error => Fix update the post

Tags: plugins, 404-error

i used Wpforms plugin for do a post submissions on Event Calendar Plugin.

For some time now, I don't know why, but all the forms posted in the Event Calendar that are properly listed are showing me a 404 error in preview.

If I edit the post without changing anything and save, I no longer get a 404 error...

I don't know how to get out of this problem, if you have any ideas?
Just editing the post and saving it fixes the 404 error when I preview the page.

thx a lot